# Creating new environments in Puppet Server

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

We are using a shared Puppet Server to manage both QA and DEV environments . The default configurations Puppet Server uses is Production environment

```
# puppet master --configprint all | grep production

environment = production
manifest = /data/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
modulepath = /data/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/data/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

I want to enable two more environments DEV and QA. For this I will copy the above directories and rename to `qa` and `development` environment respectively on Puppet Server. What configuration items to enable in `puppet.conf` to enable the new environments in Puppet Server. If I create multiple entries as in example above will it work . Please suggest .

Comment: What version are you on? You should be using [Directory Environments](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/environments.html#about-directory-environments) by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical way to configure the environment is this:

```
#Environments
[development]
     modulepath =/etc/puppet/development/modules
     manifest = /etc/puppet/development/manifest/site.pp
     manifestdir = /etc/puppet/development/manifest

[testing]
     modulepath =/etc/puppet/testing/modules
     manifest = /etc/puppet/testing/manifest/site.pp
     manifestdir = /etc/puppet/testing/manifest

[production]
     modulepath =/etc/puppet/production/modules
     manifest = /etc/puppet/production/manifest/site.pp
     manifestdir = /etc/puppet/production/manifest
```

Then you can place modules and manifests for every enviroment into these folders.

But this method is considered depricated and people are using directory based environemnts. Set `environmentpath` to `/etc/puppet/environments` and create environment folders with `modules` and `manifests` there.

For example:

```
/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/
/etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/
/etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/
/etc/puppet/environments/testing/manifests/
```

The, you can use [r10k](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k) to automagickally download these environments fron Git branches.